# React Native debug

Tags: react-native

I’m doing a React Native project. It has a bug.

The bug make the APP just exit(it can functional run a while, but suddenly...just gone). So it dose not report error. How can I find out where the problem is?

My APP used react-native-bluetooth-serial.

[My code on Github](https://github.com/HarveyAngel/SmartRobot)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running it on you simulator.
If that is so you have to use real device for testing it as simulators do not have access to bluetooth peripherals.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Genymotion or real device to use bluetooth enabled app. To test your bug you can also use "Debug JS remotely" feature of react native dev tools.

To enable dev tools in your real device, shake your device and dev menu will appear. In emulator you can press Ctrl + M to enable dev menu. then you can choose "Debug JS remotely" which will open in chrome. If you are familiar with web development then you might have used "Inspect element" feature which will open dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

The answers are right. You might be using a simulator which doesn't support bluetooth.

To know more about the crash you can check the logs natively. For android just run this inside your android folder

```
adb logcat
```

Or you can use

```
react-native log-ios
react-native log-android
```